# powershell to read multiple lines of sql

Tags: sql, powershell

I currently have a powershell script that looks like this:

```
$Query = "SELECT 
         t1.BSM_NM
        ,t1.D_DTM AS MAXDATETIME
        ,t1.TECHNOLOGY
        ,t1.VOICEDATA
        ,CASE
            WHEN t1.VOICEDATA = 'VOICE'
                 AND
                   (
                     t1.CUST_BLK_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT >= t2.MAJOR_VOICE_BLOCK AND t1.CUST_BLK_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT < t2.CRITICAL_VOICE_BLOCK
                     OR
                     t1.DRP_CALL_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT >= t2.MAJOR_VOICE_DROP AND t1.DRP_CALL_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT < t2.CRITICAL_VOICE_DROP
                     OR
                     t1.AXS_F_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT >= t2.MAJOR_VOICE_AXSFAIL AND t1.AXS_F_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT < t2.CRITICAL_VOICE_AXSFAIL
                   )
            THEN 1
            WHEN t1.VOICEDATA = 'DATA'
                 AND
                   (
                     t1.CUST_BLK_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT >= t2.MAJOR_VOICE_BLOCK AND t1.CUST_BLK_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT < t2.CRITICAL_DATA_BLOCK
                     OR
                     t1.DRP_CALL_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT >= t2.MAJOR_VOICE_DROP AND t1.DRP_CALL_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT < t2.CRITICAL_DATA_DROP
                     OR
                     t1.AXS_F_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT >= t2.MAJOR_VOICE_AXSFAIL AND t1.AXS_F_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT < t2.CRITICAL_DATA_AXSFAIL
                   )
            THEN 1
            WHEN t1.VOICEDATA = 'VOICE'
                 AND
                   (
                     t1.CUST_BLK_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT >= t2.CRITICAL_VOICE_BLOCK
                     OR
                     t1.DRP_CALL_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT >= t2.CRITICAL_VOICE_DROP
                     OR
                     t1.AXS_F_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT >= t2.CRITICAL_VOICE_AXSFAIL
                   )
            THEN 2
            WHEN t1.VOICEDATA = 'DATA'
                 AND
                   (
                     t1.CUST_BLK_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT >= t2.CRITICAL_DATA_BLOCK
                     OR
                     t1.DRP_CALL_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT >= t2.CRITICAL_DATA_DROP
                     OR
                     t1.AXS_F_CNT/t1.ATT_CNT >= t2.CRITICAL_DATA_AXSFAIL
                   )
            THEN 2
            ELSE 0
         END MAJORCRITICAL
        FROM DS3R_FH_ALL_TRIGGER_VIEW t1
        INNER JOIN
        ZDMSN.DS3R_1XRTT_TRIGGERS_THRESHOLD t2
        ON
        t1.BSM_NM = t2.BSC_NM
        AND
        t1.TECHNOLOGY = t2.TECHNOLOGY
        WHERE t1.BSM_NM = 'ARL1' and t1.D_DTM = (SELECT MAX(D_DTM) FROM DS3R_FH_1XRTT_BTS_LVL_KPI WHERE BSM_NM = 'ARL1')"      

$data_set = new-object system.data.dataset
$adapter = new-object system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter ($Query, $Connection)
[void] $adapter.Fill($data_set)
$table = new-object system.data.datatable
$table = $data_set.Tables[0]
$bsmNM = $data_set.Tables[0].Rows[0].BSM_NM
$maxDT = $data_set.Tables[0].Rows[0].MAXDATETIME
$majorC = $data_set.Tables[0].Rows[0].MAJORCRITICAL
$table | Select MAJORCRITICAL 
  {  
    if ($majorC -match "*2*" -and $majorC -match "*1*")
    if ($majorC -match "*1*" )
    if ($majorC -match "*2*")
```

the results came back as such:
[image]

it doesn't error but it doesn't seem to be doing what I want it to do. If there is a value of 1 in any of the rows in the MAJORCRITICAL column, I want it to do the 2nd if statement, if there is a 1 in one row and a 2 in another row, I want it to do the 1st if statement. The code runs, but the if statements aren't running...

Comment: You may want to try separating out your data retrieval and parsing next time to identify which is the culprit. It is easier to provide help when you know where the problem lies. Also it may help you find a solution on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You are only looking at the first row in your example, as you are not doing `foreach` or similar.

Additionally you need to use `$_` to refer to the current item in `foreach` (alias `%`)